# Configure multiple firebase project for a single flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I'm developing a flutter app, which needs at least 2 projects for 2 different environments (development and production). My flutter app is already bound to a project, and when I tried creating another firebase project and adding the flutter app to the new project, after filling the package name and SHA, it says that OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project, which probably refers to my first project. I'm a bit confused as to how should I start configuring the second project, I've tried going to the Firebase documentation, but the guide for android application starts with google-services.json which is only available to download after an application has been added to a firebase project. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: change the package name of the app to like: com.example.test

Comment: You have to use diff application Id based on env. For example com.example.myapp for production and com.example.myapp.dev for development env like this

Comment: Where do I change it so that the app has both package names? For dev environment and production environment?